# ui boostrap popover with html causing error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Something very strange is happening with my ui-boostrap popovers.  I am following the example [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) to create a ui-boostrap popover with html inside.  Which is basically

```
  <button uib-popover-html="htmlPopover" class="btn btn-default">HTML Popover</button>
```

with the following in my controller

```
  $scope.htmlPopover = $sce.trustAsHtml('<b style="color: red">I can</b> have <div class="label label-success">HTML</div> content');
```

However, the popover does not open upon click and creates the following errors upon click

```
angular.js:11598 TypeError: c.push is not a function
    at Function.E.$$addBindingInfo (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:74:101)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:213:205
    at $ (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:70:488)
    at v (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:59:443)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:52:9)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:52:26)
    at v (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:59:387)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:67:146
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:52:9)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:51:118 <div class="popover-content ng-binding" ng-bind-html="contentExp()">
```

and

```
angular.js:11598 TypeError: html.indexOf is not a function
    at htmlParser (angular-sanitize.js:205)
    at $sanitize (angular-sanitize.js:119)
    at Object.ngBindHtmlWatchAction [as fn] (angular-sanitize.js:420)
    at l.$digest (angular.js:14230)
    at angular.js:14427
    at e (angular.js:4902)
    at angular.js:5282(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11598(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8548$digest @ angular.js:14248(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14427e @ angular.js:4902(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5282
```

I am using angular version 1.3.10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Use the unminified versions of Angular / ui-bootstrap, etc for better error messages. My guess is your HTML should be under a root element, ie wrap your HTML string in a `<div>...</div>`

Comment: actually i think it was because I was using angular sanitize